# Why tox environments aren't empty but use packages installed in parent virtual environment?

Tags: python, tox

I'm still struggling with tox tool. I completely don't understand the benefit of running commands inside tox-created environments if they aren't fresh and empty.

For example, I want to run mypy in virtual environment containing the only mypy and its dependencies, but tox-created environments contains everything so-far installed in parent environment.

My `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
minversion = 2.0
envlist = py{38},mypy

[testenv:mypy]
description =
    Run type checks.
deps =
    mypy
    types-docutils
commands=
    mypy sphinxcontrib tests
```

My workflow:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ pip install tox
```

From tox output I see that everything so-far existing in virtual env is present in mypy environment.

```
$ tox -e mypy
...
py38 installed: ... zillions of packages installed from requirements.txt, plus tox and tox dependencies ...
...
```

Why tox-created envs doesn't contain the only project itself and deps listed in its `deps`?

Answer (score 1):

Both your workflow and your report does not make much sense to me.

First, there is no good reason to install `requirements.txt` in the same virtualenv as `tox`, as it is enough to `pip install tox` so `tox` is able to run.

Usually it is a good idea to have a kind of 'global' `tox` interpreter available.

You can do this by either using `pipx` as suggested in the `tox` documentation (https://tox.wiki/en/rewrite/installation.html#via-pipx), or just create a virtualenv and only install `tox` in there, and call it directly or add the `tox` binary to your path.

As a side - I help maintain the almost 300 Zope repositories on GitHub, and we use `tox` for all projects, so you never have to do a setup to run tests or linting, just clone the repository and change into the directory and run `tox`.

Given your `tox.ini` I see no reason why the mypy environment should contain anything from `requirements.txt` nor from the `tox` executable, as `tox` creates a distinct virtualenv for each project/environment.

For example, from my project [flask-reuploaded](https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded):

```
~/Projects/flask-reuploaded$ .tox/mypy/bin/pip freeze
attrs==21.2.0
click==8.0.1
coverage==6.0
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Reuploaded @ file:///home/jugmac00/Projects/flask-reuploaded/.tox/.tmp/package/1/Flask-Reuploaded-1.1.1.dev0.zip
iniconfig==1.1.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
mypy==0.910
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
packaging==21.0
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.10.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-cov==3.0.0
toml==0.10.2
tomli==1.2.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

There is nothing in there - no `tox` and no other things except the ones I specified.

I suggest you to start all over, and create a new environment for `tox`, and then delete your `.tox` folder within in your project.

Alternatively, you can also run `tox -r` to recreate your environment.

If you still have problems, you need to provide the complete output, not only a part of it.

Disclaimer: I am one of the `tox` maintainers.